# How to Join PostgreSQL JSONB Data with Foreign Table

Tags: postgresql, left-join, jsonb, supabase

I have a PostgreSQL database table with a JSONB column that contains keys to a foreign table.

The structure looks something like this.

```
Events
_ _ _ _

id:uuid
name: uuid
fields: JSONB { 
      date {},
      activities: ['uuid','uuid']
           }
...others columns
```

```
Activities
_ _ _ _ _ _ 

id: UUID
name: varchar
```

I am trying to use the query below to join the tables but I get **cannot cast type JSONB to uuid[]** or **set-returning functions are not allowed**

```
SELECT
  to_json(src) :: json AS event
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      events.id AS id,
      events.name AS name,
      events.fields -> 'time' AS time,
      events.fields ->> 'poster' AS poster,
      events.fields ->> 'address' AS address,
      categories.name AS category,
      -- array_agg(DISTINCT activities.name) AS activities,
      events.age_limit AS age_limit,
      min(tickets.price) AS least_ticket,
      events.description AS description,
      to_json(profiles.*) AS organizer,
      timezones.short_code AS timezone,
      array_agg(DISTINCT tickets.*) AS tickets,
      to_json(currencies.*) AS currency
    FROM
      events
      LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = (events.fields ->> 'category_id') :: uuid
      LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.id = Any(
        jsonb_build_array(events.fields ->> 'activities') :: uuid [ ]
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN tickets ON tickets.event_id = events.id
      LEFT JOIN profiles ON events.user_id = profiles.user_id
      LEFT JOIN currencies ON currencies.id = events.currency_id
      LEFT JOIN timezones ON events.timezone_id = timezones.id
    WHERE
      events.slug = 'annes-wedding-nqbh'
    GROUP BY
      events.name,
      categories.id,
      events.id,
      profiles.id,
      currencies.id,
      timezones.id
  ) src;
```

Please what's the best way I can join these tables and also in the case where the activities field has an array with keys & values.

Comment: Was `jsonb_build_array(events.fields ->> 'activities')` an attempt at casting the array values to text before casting them to `uuid[]`?

Comment: @Bergi no more like trying to remove it from JSONB as it refused to cast jsonb to uuid

Comment: LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.id  = any
        (events.fields -> 'activities')::uuid[]   this was my first attempt before I started experimenting. the error was **op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side**

Comment: Yes, you cannot cast `jsonb` to `uuid`, but you should be able to cast the jsonb array element to `text`, and that to `uuid` (assuming that's how you store UUIDs in JSON?). But no, `jsonb_build_array` created yet another `jsonb` value.

Comment: @Bergi yes they are stored as UUIDs

Comment: `LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.id = Any(
        jsonb_build_array(events.fields -> 'activities')::text:: uuid [ ]
      ) ` errors out to `malformed array literal: "[["3f484a43-d72b-4521-ad85-94e42cf06c4b", "0211de73-297d-45aa-8c97-ac472ecf0f16"]]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast `jsonb` to `uuid`, but you should be able to cast the jsonb array element to `text`, and that to `uuid` (assuming that's how you store UUIDs in JSON). But notice you will need to do that individually, not for the whole array at once:

```
…
LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.id IN (
  SELECT el::uuid
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(events.fields -> 'activities') AS el
)
```

Comment: `invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""3f484a43-d72b-4521-ad85-94e42cf06c4b""` thank you for your response. it errored out though

Comment: `jsonb_array_elements_text` works instead, please edit your answer so I can acknowledge it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Ah, right, I always forget that casting to `::text` does not extract the value of a json string but just creates json text. One would need `#>>'{}'` or, as you say, just use `array_elements_text` instead